# When knowledge of one event tells us nothing about another

Tags: terminology, independence, biostatistics

I have an example;

Say I have two genes on two different locations on two different chromosomes.
P(A) = gene is from location 1
P(B) = gene is from location 2

Geneticists believe that knowledge of the gene at one location tells us nothing about the gene at another location.

**So are events A and B independent or mutually exclusive?**

Mutually exclusive events cannot occur at once but both genes can exist on two different chromosomes at the same time, so shouldn't A and B be independent of each other?

I guess I am answering my own question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are answering your own question.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)):

> Two events are *independent, statistically independent, or stochastically independent* if the occurrence of one does not affect the probability of occurrence of the other.

If two events are mutually exclusive, then the presence of one event tells you that the other *cannot* occur, i.e., the presence of A implies that the probability for B is zero. This is certainly not independence. In your application, the correct term is "independent".

(Incidentally, genes are not necessarily independent, see [linkage disequilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_disequilibrium).)

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for clarifying that and for the interesting article. I could not follow all the math but it was very interesting reading about linkage disequilibrium.